# Concurrent document collaboration on local servers

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, lan, documents, google-docs

Does a concurrent office document collaboration service exist that does not rely on 3rd party servers?

By "collaboration" I mean changes made to a document are quickly visible to others that have the document open.

Office 365 and Google Docs have nice collaboration features, but they require use of their servers.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

SubEthaEdit for Mac (formerly Hydra) may have been the first realtime collaborative editor, and is still around. It's serverless; each running instance can act as a server for any open docs.

Search for "collaborative editor" for other choices. You may need to be specific about what features and platforms you require.